# This functionality is not supported by Default spatial service. DevArt dotConnect for PostgreSQL error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, well-known-binary, nettopologysuite

I want to get geometry data as binary. Its give me an error {"This functionality is not supported by Default spatial service."}. I am searching but nothing found about it.

```
var ilces = db.MaksIlces.Where(p => p.GID == 0).FirstOrDefault();
var aa = ilces.Geom.WellKnownValue.WellKnownBinary;
```

in the second line gives me this error.

Comment: Deleted my answer. This seems more related to the dotConnect configuration, wich I've never used. I've only found is this post: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=29289